# Function signatures

Tags: f#

I would like to create a function `map3` that, given a function `f` and a tuple `(a, b, c)` applies `f` to every member of the tuple. The expected signature of the function should be:

`('a -> 'b) -> 'a * 'a * 'a -> 'b * 'b * 'b` .

I tried several approaches:

```
> let map3 = fun x -> let f = fun (a, b, c) -> (a, b, c) in f x;;
val map3 : 'a * 'b * 'c -> 'a * 'b * 'c

> let map3 = fun x y -> x (let f = fun (a, b, c) -> (a, b, c) in f y);;
val map3 : x:('a * 'b * 'c -> 'd) -> 'a * 'b * 'c -> 'd

> let map3 = fun (x, y, z) -> let f = fun (a, b, c) -> (a, b, c) in f (x, y, z);; 
val map3 : x:'a * y:'b * z:'c -> 'a * 'b * 'c
```

I strongly suspect that I did not get how function signatures actually work. According to [what I get](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/function-signatures/), `map3` should have one input and one output, and `f` should take as input a triple and return a triple. But it is clearly wrong on something. What am I missing, in my attempts to implement it?

Comment: Here is a hint - start from `let map3 f = `.  Also, people don't tend to use the `in` syntax any more

Comment: I am working on it! I did not think of such an approach. You are also right about the use of `in`. The book proposed in our course is quite outdated. I am learning both the styles, just to make learning easier.

Comment: There are many F# books and you can just look at http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/fsharp-in-60-seconds/ for example.

Comment: I agree. I usually integrate with [Functional programming with F#](https://www.amazon.it/dp/1107684064/ref=asc_df_110768406446546158/?tag=googshopit-21&creative=23390&creativeASIN=1107684064&linkCode=df0&hvdev=c&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=). I like the approach across the book. It just lacks a little of exercises with solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let map3 f (x, y, z) = (f x, f y, f z)
```

you can also write it like

```
let map3 f = fun (x, y, z) -> (f x, f y, f z)
```

or

```
let map3 = fun f (x, y, z) -> (f x, f y, f z)
```

But I would prefer to have the parameters on the left side. As you can see the first version is shorter to write and easier to read.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses on the RHS of the equals sign. Nothing wrong with using them, of course. On the other hand, the argument tuple must be within parentheses in all three cases. Just my $0.02.

Comment: Yes, of course. I left them to make clear to the reader that it's a tuple, but they are optional in some cases like that one.

Comment: Thanks for your straightforward answer. It actually helped me even beyond what I asked!